# mysql how to show some rows of table depending on one field and depending on one field in other table?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a script where members login and read posts by catagory that I have in
Table called posts, then they click a button and an entry is inserted into Table
called postsread collecting the postname, their memberid, and the date showing
that it had been read by them. What I am looking for is a query that will
display to them only the posts that they have not already read.

```
**Tables**         **Fields**
posts          id, name, date, from, topic, info, cat
postsread      id, postname, memberid, date
users          id, memberid, pass, fname, lname, email
```

Sessions is already holding their $_SESSION['memberid'], but am unsure of how
to query between the two tables to get what I'm looking for.
It would be like: Show all posts in Posts except those in Postsread with the members
memberid next to the corresponding postname.
I am using php version 5.3, and mysql 5.0.96.

I am using the following to display posts from database:

`$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE cat='1' ORDER BY date DESC");`

But this does not differentiate between if the member has clicked stating they have
seen them yet or not.

I have looked many places and see examples that are close but just cant get any to
fit what I am needing. I don't fully understand how to write this. I have tried many
with no success. If you need extra description please ask. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please, do not use `mysql_query` in new code. It's a creaky old interface from PHP 2.0 that's deprecated and being removed in future versions of PHP. [Switching to PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) is usually not hard and could potentially solve a lot of [SQL escaping problems](http://bobby-tables.com/php) you might not be aware of.

Comment: why are you giving ids to each record but not using them? don't relate `postsread` to `posts` using the `name` column in `posts` (`postname` in `postsread`), use the `id`! so in the `postsread` table, you only need `postid`, `memberid`, and `date`. and possibly `id` if you need a unique identifier column.

Comment: Thank you. I will start reading up on PDO. And I will sift through pages and try and reference postsread -posts closer. The ids are created automaticly somehow. I never thought it would cause any harm so I will see why they are created. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: ids are generally a good thing - you should use them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE cat='1' AND name NOT IN (SELECT postname FROM postsread WHERE memberid='$memberid') ORDER BY date DESC") or die (mysql_error());`

Tadman was right on with his answer; I had something in the code that was not supposed to be there, but could not find it. Eventually I just rewrote the thing and it worked. The above worked for me, and I thank you Tadman for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to construct a `JOIN` condition against the `posts_read` table, or use an `IN` clause to exclude them. You should be very careful with your indexes as these sorts of queries can get extremely slow and database intensive with non-trivial amounts of data.

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE cat=:cat AND name NOT IN (SELECT postname FROM postsread WHERE memberid=:memberid)
```

Here `:cat` and `:memberid` are placeholders for the appropriate values. Using PDO you can bind directly to those using the `execute` function.

As a note, joining on strings is a lot slower than joining on `id` type values. You might want to make your `postsread` table reference `id` from `posts` instead.

Comment: I cant get this to work I just get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/content/.../cat1.php on line 1` Thank you for your help.

Comment: That looks like a syntax error. I don't even have any quotation marks in my example here.

Comment: Thanks for your help tadman. I can tell by reading your answer that it is asking for exatly what i am wanting. Maybe I am putting it in wrong. Here is all I did. `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE cat='1' AND name NOT IN (SELECT postname FROM postsread WHERE memberid=$_SESSION['userid');` I have been away from a computer for a few years now and just returning finding so many changes.

Comment: You can't just jam in session data like that. You should be using PDO, it's [not hard to pick up](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/), which allows for placeholders, but you need to use `mysql_real_escape_string` if you insist on using `mysql_query`. `$_SESSION['userid']` cannot be interpolated properly if already inside a string, at least not without some coaching.

Comment: A better alternative is: `$query = sprintf('SELECT * FROM ... memberid=%s', mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['userid']))` where you can use `%s` to represent where the subsequent values will go.